# net.trainParam.max_fail

Tags: validation, neural-network, matlab

Anyone has any comment on how to choose the validation max.fail number?
As you may know there is no unique criteria to choose a certain number. i believe that it could depends on the number of samples being used for training/validation. 
However, it has a nontrivial role in stopping the training of the neural network

Answer (score 2):

You're right, this parameter is critical for NN training. In fact, the biggest disadvantage of NNs is the presence of many critical parameters that are strongly problem-dependent, like number of neurons and training algorithm parameters such as learning rate or early stopping criteria (like in this case). In some applications, use a value of 3 or 30 is more or less the same, because after some point the NN generalization do not increase anymore, so I can suggest you to try with different parameters, including 0 and inf (i.e. no early stopping) and observe the training/validation error curves. Of course, DO NOT consider only a single run but do at least 5-10 runs for each configuration. At this point, you can try to have an idea of the "error landscape".

Answer (score 1):

Use : nnparam.max_fail

For the trainlm training function, you could type:

net.trainParam.max_fail = 10 (if you want to increase the validation fail to be 10)

From Matlab Documentation

> Maximum Validation Checks (max_fail) function parameter
>        max_fail is a training function parameter.    It must be a strictly positive integer scalar.
>        max_fail is maximum number of validation checks before    training is stopped.
>        This parameter is used by trainb, trainbfg, trainbr,    trainc, traincgb, traincgf, traincgp, traingd,    traingda, traingdm,
>   traingdx, trainlm, trainoss,    trainrp, trains and trainscg